# the average order of divisor function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

In Analytic number theory by Apostol  there's a theorem:

$$\sum_{n\le x} \sigma(n)= \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2)x^2 + O(x\log x)$$

and then it claims that because  we know that $\zeta (2)= \frac{\pi^2}{6} $ this theorem shows that the average order of $\sigma(n)$ is $\frac{\pi^2 n}{12}$

but i don't understand it because if we put $n$ instead 0f $x$ in the theorem and divide the equation by $n$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ we have:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2)n + O(\log n) $$

but it equals infinity because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \log n = \infty$.

may be it is a stupid mistake.
but what is it?

thanks

Comment: The variable $n$ is **already in use** as the dummy variable in the sum.  It doesn't make sense to "put $n$ instead of $x$" and still leave an $x$ left over in the subscript of the sum.

Comment: Please look at my edits.  This is the second of your questions in which I've cleaned up the MathJax code.

Comment: $${1\over x}\sum_{n\le x}f(n)$$ is not the same thing as $$\sum_{n\le x}{f(n)\over n}$$ as you may see if you try it with, say, $x=2$, $f(n)=n$.

Comment: Also, $\sigma(n)$ is not the divisor function, it's the sum-of-the-divisors function. The divisor function is usually denoted $d(n)$ or $\tau(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

For the average order it's enough to have
$$\frac{\sum_{n\le x}\sigma(n)}{x}(1+o(1))$$
which in this case means the error term needs only be $o(n),$ and so $O(\log n)$ is not a problem.

Comment: can u explain more please?why the error term needs only be o(n)?

Comment: Because the main term is $\Theta(n).$